# Some services are not able to be constructed & Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-6.0

Note : Working on .Net6
I have all the time having exception from code lines that I wrote down:

```
  System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed 
    (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: 
    StockProject.Bussiness.Interfaces.ICategoryService Lifetime: Singleton 
    ImplementationType: StockProject.Bussiness.CategoryService': Unable to resolve service 
    for type 'StockProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Repository`1[StockProject.Entities.Entity.Category]' 
        while attempting to activate 'StockProject.Bussiness.CategoryService'.)'
```

And also having another exception :

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
'StockProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Repository`1[StockProject.Entities.Entity.Category]' 
while attempting to activate 'StockProject.Bussiness.CategoryService'.
```

Here's my Program.cs:

```
    using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using StockProject.Bussiness;
using StockProject.Bussiness.Interfaces;
using StockProject.Bussiness.Mappings;
using StockProject.Bussiness.Repos;
using StockProject.Bussiness.ValidationRules;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Context;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Repositories;
using StockProject.Dtos.CategoryDtos;
using StockProject.Dtos.OrderDtos;
using StockProject.Dtos.ProductDtos;
using StockProject.Dtos.UserDtos;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(opt => {
    opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost",
        ValidAudience = "http://localhost",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("halil")),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };

});



builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<CategoryCreateDto>, CategoryCreateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<CategoryUpdateDto>, CategoryUpdateDtoVaildator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<OrderCreateDto>, OrderCreateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<OrderUpdateDto>, OrderUpdateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<ProductCreateDto>, ProductCreateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<ProductUpdateDto>, ProductUpdateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<UserCreateDto>, UserCreateDtoValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<UserUpdateDto>, UserUpdateDtoValidator>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRoleRepository, UserRoleRepository>();

//builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();


builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**ICategoryService:**

```
using StockProject.Common;
using StockProject.Dtos.CategoryDtos;
using StockProject.Entities.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StockProject.Bussiness.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICategoryService
    {
        Task<IResponse<CategoryCreateDto>> CreateAsync(CategoryCreateDto dto);


        Task<IResponse<List<CategoryListDto>>> GetAllAsync();


        Task<IResponse<CategoryUpdateDto>> UpdateAsync(CategoryUpdateDto dto);



        Task<IResponse> RemoveAsync(int id);


        Task<IResponse<Category>> GetByIdAsync<IDto>(int id);
        
    }
}
```

**CategoryService :**

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StockProject.Bussiness.Interfaces;
using StockProject.Bussiness.Mappings;
using StockProject.Common;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Context;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Repositories;
using StockProject.Dtos.CategoryDtos;
using StockProject.Entities.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StockProject.Bussiness
{
    public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {
        private readonly IValidator<CategoryCreateDto> _createDtoValidator;
        private readonly IValidator<CategoryUpdateDto> _updateDtoValidator;
        private readonly IRepository<Category> _repo;

        public CategoryService(IValidator<CategoryCreateDto> createDtoValidator, IValidator<CategoryUpdateDto> updateDtoValidator, Repository<Category> repo, StockProjectContext context)
        {
            _createDtoValidator = createDtoValidator;
            _updateDtoValidator = updateDtoValidator;
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public async Task<IResponse<CategoryCreateDto>> CreateAsync(CategoryCreateDto dto)
        {
            var result = _createDtoValidator.Validate(dto);
            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                //mapleme
                var mappedEntity = new Category()
                {
                    Name = dto.Name,
                };

                await _repo.CreateAsync(mappedEntity);
                return new Response<CategoryCreateDto>(true, dto);
            }
            return new Response<CategoryCreateDto>(false, dto);
        }

        public async Task<IResponse<List<CategoryListDto>>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var data = await _repo.GetAllAsync();
            var listDto = new List<CategoryListDto>();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                listDto.Add(new CategoryListDto
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Name = item.Name,

                });
            }

            return new Response<List<CategoryListDto>>(true, listDto);
        }

        public async Task<IResponse<CategoryUpdateDto>> UpdateAsync(CategoryUpdateDto dto)
        {
            var result = _updateDtoValidator.Validate(dto);
            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                var unchangedData = await _repo.GetByFilterAsync(x => x.Id == dto.Id); //.FindAsync(x);
                if (unchangedData == null)
                {
                    return new Response<CategoryUpdateDto>(false, dto);
                }
                var entity = new Category()
                {
                    Id = dto.Id,
                    Name = dto.Name,
                };
                _repo.Update(entity, unchangedData);
                return new Response<CategoryUpdateDto>(true, dto);
            }
            return new Response<CategoryUpdateDto>(false, dto);
        }


        public async Task<IResponse> RemoveAsync(int id)
        {
            var data = await _repo.GetByFilterAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            if (data == null)
                return new Response(false);
            _repo.Remove(data);
            return new Response(true);
        }

        public async Task<IResponse<Category>> GetByIdAsync<IDto>(int id)
        {
            var data = await _repo.GetByFilterAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            if (data == null)
                return new Response<Category>(false, data);
            return new Response<Category>(true, data);
        }



    }
}
```

**IRepository :**

```
using StockProject.Entities.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StockProject.DataAccess.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();

        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);

        //Task<T> FindAsync(object id);

        void Remove(T entity);

        Task CreateAsync(T entity);

        void Update(T entity, T unchanged);

        Task<T> GetByFilterAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    }
}
```

**Repository :**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Context;
using StockProject.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using StockProject.Entities.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StockProject.DataAccess.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity , new()
    {
        private readonly StockProjectContext _context;
        public Repository(StockProjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        //public async Task<T> FindAsync(object id)
        //{
        //    return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        //}

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }

        public List<T> GetAllAsync<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> selector)
        {
            var result = _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var entity = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
            return entity;
        }

        
        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(T entity, T unchanged)
        {
            _context.Entry(unchanged).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public async Task<T> GetByFilterAsync(Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

**ICategoryRepository :**

```
using StockProject.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using StockProject.Entities.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StockProject.Bussiness.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICategoryRepository  : IRepository<Category>
    {

    }
}
```

So each time having problem when I trying to start it and having exception in Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as the error indicates:
.net is  trying to create an instance of CategoryService but it doesn't know how to create  `Repository<Category> repo` to pass into the constructor.

You could check CategoryService :

```
private readonly IRepository<Category> _repo;
```

in constructor:

```
Repository<Category> repo
```

you could try to modify to `IRepository<Category> repo`in the constructor

adn it seems you didn't regist the generic service in startup,did you ?

You could check this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0